# How to force an entire partition to be recognised, after writing a smaller partition image onto it?

Tags: 16.04, partitioning

**What was done:**
Had taken a backup of `sda7` using `dd` (sda7 was around **100GB** in size).
Formatted the disk.
Used GParted from a LiveUSB to create new partitions, but this time, created `sda7` with 355GB.
Wrote the backup of `sda7` to the newly created partition using `dd`.
Used [grub tools](https://nrecursions.blogspot.com/2020/07/repairing-grub-in-dual-boot-system.html) to install grub and be able to boot.

**The problem:**
[image]
`sda7` is showing a grey area (circled in red) which I assume isn't recognized by Ubuntu as writable area.
[image]
So once I finish using up the white area in `sda7`, I assume I won't be allowed to use more than the 96.2GB shown.

I tried resizing the partition using the handle (red arrow), but I couldn't resize it.
[image]

Is there any way I can make the grey area get recognized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to resize the filesystem to fill the partition:

```
sudo resize2fs -p /dev/sda7
```

This will work while booted into the OS. Take a look at `man resize2fs` for further details.

Comment: Similar to this answer, I often print out my partition table from parted before writing a partition with dd.  Then I go back in and re-write the partition table like it was originally. However, this sounds easier.

Comment: Worked! Wow, that was super-simple.